# Use ActiveRecord to find records without an association, or given a criteria on the association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

How can I find records that either miss an association, or matches a criteria on a record association?

I have a `Reservation` model that can or cannot have a `Booking` (has_one) record associated to it. I'd like to find all records with no associations and if I do have a `Booking` associated, those that which `booking_agent` is not of class `Venue::Promoter`.

Here is my current scope to do so:

```
scope :not_requested_by_promoters, -> {
  joins("LEFT JOIN
    \"bookings\" ON \"reservations\".\"id\" = \"bookings\".\"reservation_id\"
    AND \"bookings\".\"booking_agent_type\" != 'Venue::Promoter'")
}
```

Another developer wrote the following scope, but it didn't match those records without a booking associated to it:

```
scope :not_requested_by_promoters, -> {
  joins(:booking).where('booking_agent_type != ?', "Venue::Promoter")
}
```

Both do not fulfill my requirement. What am I missing here? I've done some research and the left join should work.

Database is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` to show all `Reservations`, even those without `Bookings`. After you make the join you just need to check the records that have `bookings.reservation_id IS NULL`. This will bring only the desired results.

```
scope :not_requested_by_promoters, -> {
 joins("LEFT JOIN
   bookings ON reservations.id = bookings.reservation_id
   AND bookings.reservation_id IS NULL 
   AND bookings.booking_agent_type != 'Venue::Promoter'")
}
```

Comment: This is still finding those bookings where booking_agent_type is Venue::Promoter. Maybe PostgreSQL is doing something weird to those colons?

Comment: In the dabatase, the booking_agent_type column is recording `Venue::Promoter` as text?

Comment: Yes it is. AR ouput:
#<Booking id: 1, reservation_id: 6, booking_agent_id: 1, booking_agent_type: "Venue::Promoter", booking_type_cd: 0, created_at: "2014-04-11 20:15:10", updated_at: "2014-04-11 20:15:10">

Answer (score 0):

Thanks do Dolph at Learn Thoughtbot chat room:

```
joins('LEFT JOIN bookings ON bookings.reservation_id = reservations.id').
where("(bookings.reservation_id IS NULL)
OR (bookings.booking_agent_type != ?)", 'Venue::Promoter').
```